# Unity android forces my app to go into 16:9 with "full sreen" button instead of doing the 18:9

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, aspect-ratio, aspect

Unity android forces my app to go into 16:9 with "full sreen" button instead of doing the 18:9 as i have specified in my editor, and it used to work yesterday, but now when i restarted my pc , no settings have seemed to change but my app is forced to run in 16:9 with a blue "full screen" button. How to fix?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nKu7.png)

Comment: Please add additional details.

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 https://i.ibb.co/hfrNmCj/explaining.png